# Definition $f(x)$ diverges to negative infinity for $x \to a$

Tags: convergence-divergence, definition

Can someone tell me, if the following is a valid definition of $f(x)$ diverging to $-\infty$ for $x\to a$

> $f(x)$ diverges to $-\infty$ for $x\to a$, if and only if for all $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$, an $x<a$ exists with the property $f(x)<\epsilon$.

Comment: Why should $x$ be an integer? Consider the function $f(x) = -\frac1{x^2}$ with $a = 0$, and try out your definition there. What happens? What about the function $g(x) = x$ and $a = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: Where in your definition do you incorporate $a$?

It should rather be the following: $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=-\infty$ if for each $M\in\mathbb R$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ implies $f(x)<M$.

Comment: Oh yeah ok thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. Note that the number $a$ is not mentioned at all after the “if and only if” part of the definition. So, with this definition, the assertion “$f$ diverges to $-\infty$ as $x\to a$” would not depend upon the choice of $a$.